# Determinant of sum of squares of two matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, contest-math, determinant

**Problem :** $\rm P$ and $\rm Q$ such that $\rm P^3 = Q^3$, $\rm Q^2P = P^2Q$ and $\rm P \ne Q$. Find $\rm \det(P^2 + Q^2)$ if

**(i)** If both matrices are $3\times 3$

**(ii)** If both matrices are $n\times n$,  for $n \in \Bbb N$

---

$$\rm (P^2 + Q^2)(P+ Q) = P^3 + P^2Q + Q^2P + Q^3 = 2(P^3 + P^2Q) = 2P^2(P + Q)\tag{1}$$

Taking determinant on both sides,

$$\rm \det(P^2 + Q^2)\det(P+ Q) = 2^n\det(P^2)\det(P+Q) \\ \implies \det(P^2 + Q^2) = 2^n\det(P^2) = 2^n (\det(P))^2$$

Also, $$\rm Q^2P = P^2Q \\ \implies  (\det (Q))^2 \det P = (\det P)^2 \det(Q) \\\implies  \det P\det Q (\det Q - \det P) = 0 $$

Therefore $\rm \det P = 0$ or $\rm \det Q = 0$ or $\rm \det P = \det Q$.

If $\rm\det P =0$ then I can say $\rm \det(P^2 + Q^2) = 0$ but I am not sure about other case, i.e when $\rm \det Q = 0$ or $\rm \det P = \det Q$. Can I still say $\rm \det(P^2 + Q^2) = 0$ ?

Comment: Your problem statement is symmetric with respect to $P\leftrightarrow Q$, so the case $\det Q=0$ is essentially the same.

Comment: @DietrichBurde/Ivan Neretin And when $\det P = \det Q$ ?

Comment: Then $\det(P)=\det(Q)\neq 0$ and both $P$ and $Q$ are invertible.

Comment: @123 In your first derivation you seem to implicitly assume that $\det(P+Q)\ne0$; is that necessarily true?

Comment: For example, let $$P=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix},\;Q=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1&0\\0&0&-1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ The conditions are met, but you can't say that $\det(P^2 + Q^2) = 2^n\det(P^2)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial idea just needs a little tweak: instead of multiplying by $\rm P+Q$, let's multiply by $\rm P-Q$:
$$\rm (P^2+Q^2)(P-Q)=P^3-P^2Q+Q^2P-Q^3=0.$$

If $\rm \det(P^2+Q^2)\neq0$, then $\rm P^2+Q^2$ is invertible, and we can multiply by its inverse:
$$\rm (P^2+Q^2)(P-Q)=0 \implies P-Q=(P^2+Q^2)^{-1}0=0,$$
contradicting the given condition that $\rm P\neq Q$.